# After upgrade to Office 2010 Standard in RDS environment, ribbon has gone missing

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, microsoft-office-2010

Last night on my RDS server (Server 2008 R2) I upgraded Office 2007 to Office 2010 and Outlook has no ribbon. It's even missing the tab titles in the minimized ribbon view. That is, on my machine, when the ribbon is minimized I can still see the tab titles. On the server there are no tabs.

I have not found any relevant searches on Google or this site and I've tried restarting the server as well as deleting a user profile. Unless there is a way to bring it back my next option is to uninstall/reinstall.

My Outlook with ribbon minimized:

[image: My Outlook with ribbon minimized]

Outlook on server with ribbon minimized.

[image: Outlook on server with ribbon minimized]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRM 2011 client addin blocks the ribbon in Outlook in a specific scenario. Here's the KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2494581

Answer (score 0):

You could try a repair install - this should be painless. I assume it's the same if you create a brand new user, too?

You don't mention what Operating System you're running, but did you install it in install mode? This is especially important if you're on Server 2003.

Comment: RDS (Remote Desktop Services) was introduced in Server 2008 R2 which is why I neglected to state the version explicitly. But I should always do that for completeness sake.

Honestly I thought install mode had gone away with 2008 R2 for some reason. Little did I know! I will try the repair install first and then revert to a previous snapshot and install in Install Mode.

Comment: You're absolutely right - to be honest, I took the RDS terminology with a pinch of salt. I still use install mode, but its mostly habit from switching between new and old installs. I doubt if it is a factor here.

Comment: I think I may have found the culprit by troubleshooting a user's seemingly unrelated problem. We use Microsoft CRM and the plugin appears to be blocking the ribbon. When I disable the plugin the ribbon appears immediately. Enabling makes it disappear. I probably have to reinstall the CRM Outlook client to align the bits (or something).

Comment: Nice one - if it is the case, add it as an answer then mark it as such.